# Convert Integer to Hex with result always having 2 bytes

Tags: python, usb

I'd like to convert an array of integer values I have received over USB using pyusb to a list of hex values.  I'd like these hex values to always have two bytes, i.e. 0x##.  However the normal hex() function will return 0x1 with an input of 1.  I'd like it to return 0x01.

Then after having the list of hex values I'd like to append them together while throwing away the '0x' portion.  This is what I currently have, pretty simple.

```
data_read = dev.read(0x82,64,0,1000)
hex_data = range(0,len(data_read))

for i in range(0,len(data_read)):
    hex_data[i] = hex(data_read[i])
```

Any ideas?  I can fudge it and do it the sloppy way, but I was hoping there is a proper  way to do it.  Thank you.

Update:

```
 data_read = dev.read(0x82,64)
 print data_read
 >>> array('B', [169, 86, 128, 1, 0, 128])
 for i in range(0,len(data_read)):
      hex_data[i] = hex(data_read[i])
 print hex_data
 >>> ['0xa9', '0x56', '0x80', '0x1', '0x0', '0x80']
```

The method suggested by Lavon did not work since the resulting hex values were technically strings in my code?  Instead I just skipped my whole for loop converting to hex and directly did as Lavon and moooeeeep suggested and it worked!  Thanks!

```
hex_data = ('%02x' %i for i in data_read)
print ''.join(hex_data)
>>> a95680010080
```

Is there a good reference you use for syntax?  i.e. the '%02x' you used?  I haven't seen that before and would like to understand it better.

Comment: Those aren't bytes. Those are [nibbles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble).

Comment: In `dev.read(0x82,64,0,1000)` are all the values hex or only the values with the leading `0x`?

Comment: @senderle yeah brain fart there, late day

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation that shows the various string formatting options: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting. They are similar to the ones used in C. Python now also uses additional newer formatting directives.

Comment: Thanks, just figured it out by experimentation.  I'm a non software guy relying on High School days of Java to get me through OOP, so all the syntax is pretty fresh to me.  Thanks again, great community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this fit the bill?

```
data = [0x1, 0x4, 0x5, 0xFF, 0x12]

new_data = ['%02X' %i for i in data]
print ''.join(new_data)
```

yields:

```
010405FF12
```

using list comprehension and the join operation.

Alternatively, as suggested by @moooeeeep here is the solution using a generator:

```
new_data = ('%02X' %i for i in data)
print ''.join(new_data)
```

For the string formatting options, see [this](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Comment: better use a generator `()` instead of the list comprehension `[]`.

Comment: @moooeeeep hi .. could you explain why a generator would be preferable? Not trying to disagree, but I also don't know the reason. Thanks.

Comment: it generates `new_data` on-the-fly thus saving memory (not the entire list needs to be available at the same time). See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Comment: @moooeeeep thanks, good point -- I remember now. It's similar to how `range` and `xrange` work with Python 2.x. Appreciate the note.

Comment: @Levon thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't quite work.  I missed a step here explaining my data formats, I'll edit my original post to be more specific.

Comment: I updated the solution to include the use of a generator too.

Answer (score 1):

> Then after having the list of hex values I'd like to append them together while throwing away the '0x' portion.

Do you mean something like this:

```
In [8]: data_read = [0x01, 0x2b, 0x22, 0x10]

In [9]: ''.join(map(lambda v: '%02x' % v, data_read))
Out[9]: '012b2210'
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it

```
>>> data_read = [0x01, 0x2b, 0x22, 0x10]
>>> ("{:02x}"*len(data_read)).format(*data_read)
'012b2210'
```